# How to prevent babel from transpiling generator functions

Tags: node.js, babeljs

I have kind of a weird problem with babel. When I use a simple generator function in one of my classes, babel creates a function out of it containing a call to `regeneratorRuntime`.

```
var marked3$0 = [getQueryDummy].map(regeneratorRuntime.mark);
function getQueryDummy(start, end, step) {
    return regeneratorRuntime.wrap(function getQueryDummy$(context$4$0) {
```

Bad thing is, it doesn't create this function which always results in an error when I forget to manually replace the compiled generator with the original one (which happens all the time)

I know I can add

```
require('babel/polyfill')
```

to my file. The polyfill holds the `regeneratorRuntime` function. And here is where it's getting really weird. Even though I place the require(...)
at the very top of the file, babel calls `regeneratorRuntime` before the polyfill is included, which again leads to the same error.

For completeness sake, here's the generator

```
function *getQueryDummy(start, end, step) {
  while (start < end) {
    yield [start, '@dummy'];
      start += step;
  }
}
```

I'm using babel version `5.8.23`.

Is there a way to tell babel to not touch `generators` at all? node supports them natively and there's no need for me to compile it...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could [blacklist](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/) `regenerator`. If you're building with `transform`:

```
babel.transform(code, {blacklist:['regenerator']});
```

Or from command line with:

```
--blacklist regenerator
```

Comment: Is there a way to blacklist via .babelrc?

Answer (score 0):

We can also use exclude  https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#exclude

And make use of .babelrc