# ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

Tags: javascript, babeljs, rollup, rollupjs

I'm using `rollup` to build a module from my project, and it's not including `regeneratorRuntime`. What am I missing here?

```
module.exports = {
  external: [],
  entry: './src/appProxypass/index.js',
  dest: './packages/proxypass-app/index.js',
  format: 'cjs',
  plugins: [
    require('rollup-plugin-commonjs')({
    }),
    require('rollup-plugin-babel')({
      babelrc: false,
      runtimeHelpers: true,
      // externalHelpers: true,
      'presets': [
        'es2015-rollup',
        'stage-2'
      ],
      'plugins': [
        'transform-async-to-generator',
        'syntax-async-functions',
        'transform-flow-strip-types',
        'transform-class-properties'
      ],
      exclude: 'node_modules/**'
    }),
    require('rollup-plugin-cleanup')()
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you try to add blacklist: regenerator

Comment: See (the duplicate?) here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32995587/how-to-prevent-babel-from-transpiling-generator-functions

Comment: @baao I added `"transform-runtime",` and it seems to work. Just gives me this error I cant get rid of `The 'createClass' Babel helper is used more than once in your code. It's strongly recommended that you use the "external-helpers" plugin or the "es2015-rollup" preset. See https://github.com/rollup/rollup-plugin-babel#configuring-babel for more information`.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you further, I didn't use that in quite some while, only had that question when I used it and yours seemed familiar. Babel seems to change stuff quite often quite tremendously, but if you use one of the recommended plugins instead it should work, no?